# Having a problem with unmet dependencies. I have tried apt-get clean/remove/update/upgrade, etc. Nothing works. How can I fix this

Tags: package-management, dependencies

```
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic (3.13.0-52.85) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-52-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-52-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-52-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_7zDk7K/lib/modules/3.13.0-52-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_7zDk7K/lib/modules/3.13.0-52-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic (3.13.0-95.142) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.13.0-95-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-95-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-95-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-95-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-95-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_l3Q319/lib/modules/3.13.0-95-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_l3Q319/lib/modules/3.13.0-95-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-95-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-95-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: "gzip: stdout: No space left on device" What does this tell us? `df -h`

Comment: This is the result: Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  292G   49G  229G  18% /
none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                         910M  8.0K  910M   1% /dev
tmpfs                        185M  1.1M  184M   1% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         924M   84K  924M   1% /run/shm
none                         100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    236M  234M     0 100% /boot

Comment: @chili555 - [ls /boot/
abi-3.13.0-38-generic         initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
abi-3.13.0-39-generic         initrd.img-3.13.0-51-generic
abi-3.13.0-44-generic         lost+found
abi-3.13.0-46-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.13.0-48-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-3.13.0-49-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin]

Comment: [config-3.13.0-38-generic      System.map-3.13.0-38-generic
config-3.13.0-39-generic      System.map-3.13.0-39-generic
config-3.13.0-44-generic      System.map-3.13.0-44-generic
config-3.13.0-46-generic      System.map-3.13.0-46-generic
config-3.13.0-48-generic      System.map-3.13.0-48-generic
config-3.13.0-49-generic      System.map-3.13.0-49-generic
grub                          vmlinuz-3.13.0-38-generic]

Comment: grub                          vmlinuz-3.13.0-38-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-38-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-39-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic